# Install failed container error

Tags: android, slidingmenu

**Application 1:**
My project almost 90 percentage finished, at this stage I was trying to create widget for my app when I was running after creating and adding the widget successfully to the project the error `INSTALL FAILED CONTAINER ERROR` occurs. Ok now I just tried to delete the `.asec` (i.e `/mnt/secure/asec/example.asec`) which is not working for me. I also tried to set the installation location `android:installLocation="auto"` which is not also working. Finally I decided to delete my Widget (Class, layout and everything related with the widget) and then tried still the error `INSTALL FAILED CONTAINER ERROR` occurs

**Application 2:**
And One more problem with my one more application which is also at 90 percentage of finishing state, it shows

`08-18 23:03:38.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3235): FATAL EXCEPTION: main`

`08-18 23:03:38.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3235): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu`

`08-18 23:03:38.928: E/AndroidRuntime(3235): at in.blogspot.pcnlap.skillgun3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)`

This is a `Jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu` I ran this second application more than 100 times for testing purpose at that time it did'nt showed any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manifest file set the property android:installLocation="internalOnly" and when starting your avd remember to wipe the user data. This may fix the error your seeing.